# How to make this class deserializable

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I have some xml that i get from a service that looks like this

```
<Pools>
    <Pool Code="WN" Name="Win" /> 
    <Pool Code="PL" Name="Place" /> 
    <Pool Code="SH" Name="Show" /> 
    <Pool Code="EX" Name="Exacta" /> 
    <Pool Code="PE" Name="Perfecta (Exacta)" /> 
</Pools>
```

I want to deserialize that into the following classes

```
public class Pools : List<Pool>
{
    public Pools() { }
public Pools(int capacity) : base(capacity){ }
}

public class Pool
{
    [XmlAttribute("Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Pool() {}

    public Pool(string code, string name)
    {
        Code = code;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

But it keeps failing and im not sure what im doing wrong...
I have a feeling its an issue with the Pools class but im not sure what to apply to make it work

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you need to make `Pools` a property on a class with the `[XmlElement("Pool")]` attribute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this the other way around and you'll quickly find the problem.  Your Pools class requires the [XmlRoot] attribute to ensure the element name isn't "ArrayOfPools".

```
[XmlRoot("Pools")]
public class Pools : List<Pool> {
   // etc...
}
```